# How to get data from one collection and insert into another collection in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, collections, insert

Am using Nodejs and MongoDB and I am new to nodejs. I need to know how to get data from one collection and append some additional data and insert into another collection.

```
db.collection('collection1').find({ "Id" : 12345 }).toArray(function(err, result){ 
   db.collection('collection2', function(err, collection){
       collection.insert({
          //some data
       })
   })
})
```

When I try this code its not working its giving me error insert is not defined.

thanks,
John.

Comment: You are going to need to control callbacks when looping in most real cases. With a very small collection you could throw a whole array at insert. Anything else you should probably be using a "cursor" instead of `.toArray()` and process each result of that. It depends on what you actually want to do here, and the size of the collection. That part is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection('collection1').find({ "Id" : 12345 }).toArray(function(err, result){ 
 //do the modification here 
 db.collection('collection2').insert(modifiedResult, function(err, result){
        if(err) {
            //log error
        }else{
            //log result
        }
    })
})
```

One more thing, If the result array length is more that one and you want to insert then separately then use promise

```
db.collection('collection1').find({ "Id" : 12345 }).toArray(function(err, result){ 
 //do the modification here 
  Promise.all(modifiedResult.map((eachModifiedResult)=>{
       return db.collection('collection2').insert(eachModifiedResult);
  }).then((result)=>{
      //result of the insert
  }).catch((err){
     //err if any happen
 });
})
```

But if you have a very large doc then do it as Neil Said. Read the collection one by one using cursor and modify them and insert them to other db.

Comment: Pretty sure the question is asking to insert everything from the `result` array here. Can't see how adding `if` and `else` really helps with that.

Comment: it just if he is able to insert the doc or not.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use callback library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or Promises [Q
>   Promise](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/)

```
var collectionData = null;
var modifiedResult = null;
```

> // here i am using async library to avoid [callbackHell](http://callbackhell.com/)

```
async.series([
    // for get data from collection 1.    
    function(cb) {
        var criteria = {
            "Id": 12345
        }
        db.collection('collection1').find(criteria).toArray(function(dbErr, dbResult) {
            if (err) {
                cb(dbErr)
            } else {
                collectionData = dbResult;
                cb()

            }
        })
    },
    // Append Data in collectionData
    function(cb) {

        // do you work here to append data in collectionData

        modifiedResult = extendedData; // this is just an example you need to work on it 
        cb();

    },
    // Update collection 2 here 
    function(cb) {
        db.collection('collection2').insert(modifiedResult, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                cb(dbErr)
            } else {
                collectionData = dbResult;
                cb()

            }
        });
    }

]);
```